# Installing SSL Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install an SSL certificate on my Apache server that's hosted on an EC2 instance from AWS. I originally intended to go with AWS Certificate Manager and put the SSL on a Load Balancer but I have no need for more than one EC2 instance.

What I have found is that you can install the SSL directly to the server that's hosted at AWS. What I am confused about is how to do it. https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm, among others, is a link that I have been trying to follow. I am stuck at #2 in the digicert link above becuase I can't find the SSL configuration file. Is it possible that I could not have that set up? If so, do I create the virtual host like specified in #4? Where would I place the virtual host block of code in my server?

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html

If you can't find the SSL config file in /etc/httpd/conf.d it's because you don't have mod_ssl installed on your server. mod_ssl works for Apache version 2.2. mod24_ssl will not work for Apache version 2.2 but 2.4. I used command sudo yum install -y mod_ssl and it worked fine on my instance since I had version 2.2.

If anyone needs any more explanation on this issue, let me know. I figured it out from scratch and would be more than happy to help someone else avoid the confusion/frustration. It's pretty straight forward once you can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put ssl certificate inside tomcat on ec2 instance, then you can take an image of that instance and update image on amazon autoscale. The steps for installing ssl certificate in tomcat server, you can find on different links, google on this and you will find many links. While i am providing some below links, hope these helps :

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl